# ERROR: column reference is ambiguous Position in Tableau for mac

Tags: tableau-desktop

I get this error
'ERROR: column reference is ambiguous Position. Error Code 6BF19D1C'
running the next query on Tableau for mac on PostgreSQL 15.2

```
SELECT *
FROM magasin
  join ville_mag
    on magasin.ville = ville_mag.ville
  join vente_bonbon
    on magasin.nom_site = vente_bonbon.nom_site
```

But this query works fine in admin panel or VSCode connected to that DB.
Ass well i tried other join types and put semicolon at the end but nothing helped

Comment: If the columns being joined have incompatible data types or if there are no matching values in the tables, the query may return unexpected results or errors.

Comment: but how does the same query works from admin panel? in the case what you're talking about should be error happed anyway. But the error occurs in Tableau only

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that is a bug and I found a workaround: instead of *** operator** we need to spread all needed columns in select query

so final solution will be like this:

```
SELECT magasin.nom_site,
       responsable,
       adresse,
       code_postal,
       magasin.ville,
       libelle,
       departement,
       id_vente,
       nombre,
       poids,
       ca,
       nom,
       mois
FROM magasin
    join ville_mag
        on magasin.ville = ville_mag.ville
    join vente_bonbon
        on magasin.nom_site = vente_bonbon.nom_site
```